# user registration with react-query and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-query

I am using firebase authentication in my project and i am also using react-query. this is how i am implementing user registration

```
const addNewDoc = ({ name, price, uid }) => {
  const ref = doc(usersDb, uid);
  return setDoc(ref, { name, price });
};

const register = ({ email, password }) => {
  return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
};

const Register = () => {
  const addOtherFields = useMutation(addNewDoc);
  const newUser = useMutation(register, {
    onSuccess(data) {
      addOtherFields.mutate({ name: "John", price: "20", uid: data.user.uid });
    },
  });

  const submit = () => {
    newUser.mutate({ email: "john@gmail.com", password: "123456" });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={submit}>register</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

i am using 2 useMutation here. first one is for creating a user with given email and password and Second mutation is for creating a new document in "users" collection with additional information about the user. Is there a better way to do this?

i am setting the document name to be the uid got back from the response of first mutation

i couldn't find any resource on firebase authentication using react-query. please share any link if there is.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the mutation function like this.

```
    const register = async ({ email, password, name, price }) => {
      const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      return setDoc(doc(usersDb, response.user.uid), { name, price })
    };
    
    const Register = () => {
      
      const newUser = useMutation(register);
    
      const submit = () => {
        newUser.mutate({ email: "john@gmail.com", password: "123456", name: "John", price: "20" });
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={submit}>register</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

By doing this I can avoid using another useMutation.